# Finding the local maximum from a select amount of rows

Tags: python, matplotlib

An important part of my code is to take the maximum over rows ranging from values of 3500 angstroms (an astronomical unit) to 7000 angstroms. However, the maximum value that my function is calling is out of the range. How would I call a certain range of rows in my file?

```
%matplotlib notebook 
import numpy as np                           #import python tools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

file1 = 'spectra1.dat'                #call the first file
spectra1 = np.loadtxt(file1, skiprows=3)

fig= plt.figure()                            #plotting the data for the figure below
plt.title('spectral atlas', fontname="times new roman", fontsize=15)
#title
axes=fig.add_subplot(111)                    #create dimensions for graph
plt.ylabel('Normalized Flux ', fontname="times new roman") #Label for Y axis
plt.xlabel('Wavelength ($\AA$)', fontname="times new roman")        #Label for X axis 
plt.xlim(3500,7000)
plt.ylim(0,3)

ymax = max(spectra1[:,1])
print(ymax)
norminc1 = (spectra1[:,1]/ymax)+1

axes.plot(spectra1[:,0], norminc1, label= 'normalized flux of spectra1')

plt.legend(loc=1, prop={'size': 7})          #create legend, moving it to top right and decreasing size
plt.show()
```

Comment: `ymax = max(spectra1[3500:7000,1])`

Comment: Using ymax = max(spectra1[3500:7000,1]) results in the maximum values of the second column from rows 3500 to 7000. I am trying to find the maximum value of the second column between the values of 3500 and 7000 found in the first column